# enums - indirect case is "reference" for associated value, why/how is it persistent?

Tags: swift

```
enum List<Element> {
    case end
    case anotherEnd
    indirect case node(Element, next: List<Element>)
}
var listA = List<Int>.end
var listB = List<Int>.node(5, next: listA)
listA = .anotherEnd
if case let .node(_, next: n) = listB {
    print(n)
}
```

This code prints *end*, and not *anotherEnd*. Enums are value types, OK. How/why works the reference layer? Copy-on-write? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `indirect` case is implemented as a reference to a heap allocated box containing the payload. There's no copy-on-write because enumerations are immutable (i.e you have to re-assign to `self` to actually do a 'mutation'), so value semantics is preserved even with such a reference.

You could re-write your example like this and the behaviour wouldn't change:

```
enum List<Element> {

  final class NodeRef {

    let element: Element
    let next: List

    init(element: Element, next: List) {
      self.element = element
      self.next = next
    }
  }

  case end
  case anotherEnd
  case node(NodeRef)
}

var listA = List<Int>.end
var listB = List<Int>.node(List.NodeRef(element: 5, next: listA))
listA = .anotherEnd

if case let .node(n) = listB {
  print(n.next) // end
}
```

You're just changing the value of `listA`, it has no bearing on the value of `listB`.